# Shorten path in zsh prompt

Tags: zsh, prompt

`Bash` has the `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` option, e.g. when I set `PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3`, then a long path like:

```
user@computer: /this/is/some/silly/path
```

would show instead as:

```
user@computer: .../some/silly/path
```

Does a similar option exist for `zsh`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To get a similar effect like in `bash`, that is including the `...`, try using:

```
%(4~|.../%3~|%~)
```

in in your `PROMPT` variable (which might be also named `PS1` in your configuration) place of `%~`.
This checks, if the path is at least 4 elements long (`%(4~|true|false)`) and, if true, prints some dots with the last 3 elements (`.../%3~`), otherwise the full path is printed (`%~`).

---

I noticed that `bash` seems to shorten paths in the home directory differently, for example:

```
~/.../some/long/path
```

For a similar effect, you may want to use:

```
%(5~|%-1~/…/%3~|%4~)
```

This checks, whether the path is at least 5 elements long, and in that case prints the first element (`%-1~`), some dots (`/…/`) and the last 3 elements. It is not exactly the same as paths, that are not in your home directory, will also have the first element at the beginning, while `bash` just prints dots in that case. So

```
/this/…/some/silly/path
```

instead of

```
.../some/silly/path
```

But this might not necessarily a bad thing.

---

Instead of `%~` you can also use `%d` (or your current `PROMPT` might already use `%d`). The difference is, that `%d` shows full absolute paths, while `%~` shows shorthands for “named directories”: e.g. `/home/youruser` becomes `~` and `/home/otheruser` becomes `~otheruser`. If you prefer to use the full path as basis for the shortening, just replace any occurrence of `~` with `d`.

Comment: I like the first version better, but note that it shows `~/a/b` as `.../a/b` instead of `~/a/b`. To fix that, you can use `%(5~|…/%3~|%~)`.

Comment: For those new to zsh (like me), you want to use this syntax with the `PROMPT` environment variable in your `.zprofile`, e.g.: `EXPORT PROMPT="%(5~|%-1~/…/%3~|%4~)"`

Comment: @RyanH. Thanks, reading my answer again I notice, that I never mentioned, where these settings need to be made. I will have to fix that. Two small things about your comment: settings for interactive shell sessions should be made in `.zshrc` and there is really no need to `export` any shell internal parameters like `PROMPT`.

Comment: @Adaephon Thanks for the info. I will fix! :)

Comment: For what it’s worth, this `%(4~|.../%3~|%~)` actually checks whether the path is longer than **or equal to** four elements.

Comment: Where do you put `%(5~|…/%3~|%~)`? Directly putting it in `.zshrc` doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the other answers given here, you can also use `%<` to truncate the path to a given number of *characters*.  I find this preferable to using `%<n>d`, since individual path elements may obviously be quite long in themselves.  Using `%<` yields a far more predictable maximum prompt length.

For example, to left-truncate the path element with tilde expansion (`%~`) to 15 characters, replacing removed characters with `..`, you can do something like this:

```
PROMPT='%n@%m:%15<..<%~%<<%# '
```

This is documented in the Zsh manual under [Prompt Expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html), right at the end of the page.

Answer (score 5):

See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html or `man zshmisc`

```
%d
%/
Current working directory. If an integer follows the ‘%’, it specifies a number of trailing components of the current working directory to show

%~
As %d and %/, but if the current working directory starts with $HOME, that part is replaced by a ‘~’.
```

So to get something similar to `PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3`, you could use `%3d` or `%3~`, e.g.

```
% mkdir -p ~/a/b/c/d
% cd ~/a/b/c/d
% PS1='%n@%m: %3d%% '
user@computer: b/c/d%
```

Comment: This won't show the "..." like in bash, though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `%3d` [prompt expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html):

```
/home/cuonglm/.config/fish/functions $ PS1='%3d $ '
.config/fish/functions $
```

The general form is `%d`, if any positive integer follow `d` specifies the trailing components to show of current path, zero mean show the whole path, negative integer means the leading path to show:

```
.config/fish/functions $ PS1='%-2d $ '
/home/cuonglm $
```