# Displaying only final branch of current working directory on command prompt?

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh

My current command prompt displays the entire path from my home directory to my cwd. For instance a possible command prompt would be `~/Desktop/images/japan λ`. How do I make it such that it always shows only the most precise location in my cwd. For example the previous command prompt  would instead be `japan λ` or `~/japan λ`.

My current zshrc file which implements my command prompt contains:

```
PS1='%F{cyan}%~ %B%F{yellow}λ%f%b '
RPS1='%B%(?.%F{green}✓.%F{red}✗)%f%b'
PS2='%B%F{yellow}⤷%f%b '
```

Comment: I don't know about zsh, but bash allows commands inside the prompt, such as `PS1='$(basename $PWD) # '`

Comment: Related: [Shorten path in zsh prompt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273529/shorten-path-in-zsh-prompt)

Answer (score 4):

Looking at http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html it shows that you can do this by giving the `%~` prompt expansion in PS1 an integer right after the percentage sign.

```
PS1='%F{cyan}%1~ %B%F{yellow}λ%f%b '
```

The 1 after the percent will get you what you want.