# Customize zsh prompt to start at a specified directory and show all subdirectories

Tags: shell, zsh, prompt

My current prompt looks like:

```
luke@Lukes-MacBook-Pro ~/Documents/abc %
```

which uses `PROMPT='%n@%m %~ %# '` in my `.zshrc` file.

My `.zshrc` also contains `cd abc` since this is where I would like to start all terminal sessions from.

My aim is to have the prompt start at the `abc` directory and display subdirectories, always with `abc` as the starting point:

```
luke@Lukes-MacBook-Pro abc %

luke@Lukes-MacBook-Pro abc/subdirectory %
```

ie. remove `~/Documents/` from the prompt.

There are a number of posts which address similar issues, but these focus on shortening the length of prompt by limiting the number of characters ([here for example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273529/shorten-path-in-zsh-prompt))

Answer (score 0):

As for ZSH, I cannot get anything to work. I would assume that you could possibly do it if you could get the expression in tick marks (`) to expand into the variable, much like this:

Here is how to do it in BASH (put it in your .bashrc file):

```
cd /home/$USER/Documents/abc
export PS1='$USER@$HOSTNAME `echo $PWD | sed 's/\/home\/$USER\/Documents\/abc/abc/"` %~ %'
```

I apologize that this doesn't strictly answer your question, but I hope it does help.